# Problem with mapping servlet in RESTful web application

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a problem with deploying simple helloworld restful web application on Tomcat 9 in java 8 in IntelliJ. Only thing I recive is index.jsp page under `http://localhost:8080/Rozpro2_war_exploded/`
On addresses `../Rozpro2_war_exploded/rest | ../Rozpro2_war_exploded/rest/hello | ../rest | ../rest/hello | ../Rozpro2/hello | ../hello` I get HTTP Status 404 – Not Found, both in browser and in Postman
web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
        version="4.0">
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
           <param-value>services</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWrold class:

```
package services;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello,I am text!";
    }


    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello,I am xml!" + "</hello>";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello,I am html!" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }
}
```

Index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hey
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml as I import stuff with maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>services</groupId>
    <artifactId>Rozpro2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.29</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Run configuration:
[run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TgVS.png)

When I run Tomcat server I get logs:

```
[2020-03-15 11:55:24,049] Artifact Rozpro2:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
15-Mar-2020 11:55:25.539 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2020-03-15 11:55:27,512] Artifact Rozpro2:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2020-03-15 11:55:27,512] Artifact Rozpro2:war exploded: Deploy took 3,463 milliseconds
```

web.xml is in WEB-INF and I can see services in out/artifacts/Rozpro2_war_exploded/WEB-INF/services with HelloWorld.java inside.
Does anybody have any idea why I'm not able to get any response from defined url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was deploying exploded artifact and was running it not with debug. Apparently Exploded can be works only in debug, and archived works on both with and without debug.